# How to run an Ubuntu NFS V4 kernel server in an Ubuntu docker instance without port mapper?

Tags: linux, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nfs

I need to operate a NFS server in docker in pure V4 mode, i.e. without portmapper port 111. (Reason: NFS server in Docker in WSL2 in Windows.)

I found instructions how to operate the Ubuntu default kernel NFS server without port 111 being open:

From https://peteris.rocks/blog/nfs4-single-port/

```
$ sudo vim /etc/default/nfs-kernel-server
...
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--no-nfs-version 2 --no-nfs-version 3 --nfs-version 4 --no-udp"
RPCNFSDOPTS="--no-nfs-version 2 --no-nfs-version 3 --nfs-version 4 --no-udp"
...
$ sudo systemctl disable --now rpcbind.service rpcbind.socket
$ sudo systemctl mask rpcbind.service rpcbind.socket
```

However, this instructions rely on the commands "systemctl disable/mask" which are not available in my Ubuntu docker image, as there's no systemd or init around naturally in docker. When I exclude versions 2 and 3 in /etc/default/kernel-server and start nfs, I get the error message:

```
Not starting: portmapper is not running
```

Questions:

- How can I run a pure NFS V4 tftp server in docker (Ubuntu) that does not need portmapper / port 111 ?
- How can I do systemctl disable --now rpcbind-service rpcbind-socket and systemctl mask epcbind-service rpcbind.socket when I have no systemctl available ?
- Do I maybe need to patch /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server start ?
- Are there better alternatives to nfs-kernel-server for a pure V4 mode ?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

A) Disable check for rpcbind in init script

```
sudo vim /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server
```

Remove 8 lines near #See if rpcbind is running ... if ...fi

B) Use --privileged when starting rocker run